# Как использовать клиента как прокси?

Tags: linux, proxy

Есть клиент и есть сервер. Сервер должен получить некоторую информацию, сделать какие-то действия с аккаунтом пользователя на другом сайте, но не должен делать это со своего IP. Я хочу чтобы сервер мог отправлять запросы через IP клиента, но я не могу дать ему софт, который сделает нужные действия, т.к. мне нужно нужно на сервере получить результат действий, а клиент  может подменить ответ и сервер получит неверные данные, которые я не могу проверить. По сути мне надо поднять на клиенте прокси сервер, но вот я не могу на нем открывать порты, да и запросы отправляться будут только когда клиент захочет, когда он сам попросит сервер сделать это. Самое простое решение это поднять прокси сервер (squid например) и пробросить порт через SSH туннель, но тут сразу 2 проблемы:

1. Клиент получает доступ к серверу по SSH, а мне это не надо.
2. Клиенту придется залезать в putty, пробрасывать порты, вводить пароль, сложно. Надо чтобы все само сделалось и не было уязвимостей. Да, я могу софтом создать ssh соединение, им же ввести пароль, но этот пароль могут вытащить из софта и взломать сервер.
   Я себе представляю идеальное решение как некий прокси сервер на сервере, к которому подключается софт клиента по websocket или еще как-то (в идеале не палить IP сервера, через cloudflare сделать, иначе задудосят). Клиент подает сигнал серверу, тот пользуясь прокси сервером на сервере передает запросы клиенту, а клиент через него же передает софту на сервере ответы.
   Как такое сделать или может можно как-то лучше сделать, чтобы прокси сервер клиента подключался к моему серверу сам, а не я к нему?

Comment: Какая-то несумятица уже в первом предложении. Можете переформулировать понятнее?

Comment: @0andriy так лучше?

Comment: Это вообще нормально на stackoverflow обсуждать malware? ... "иначе задудосят" - ну так и правильно сделают.

Comment: Ну все делается с разрешения клиента, это нужно для подтверждения его работы на другом сайте. Человек выполняет задания, а я должен удостовериться в выполнении, а сайт может забанить аккаунты, если с 1 IP на все аккаунты запросы слать, 1 клиент получает бан и все остальные по IP получают тоже. Прокси дорого выходят, аккаунтов многовато. Я боюсь что найдутся те, кто будут подменять ответы серверу и слать фейковую информацию о выполнении задания. Может вы тогда знаете как обезопасить себя от такого?

Comment: например: [SSH Reverse socks tunnel](https://superuser.com/q/370930/454489) + [command в authorized_keys](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178576+authorized_keys+command). плюс: сеанс оболочки на сервере запустить не получится. минус: у клиента надо будет запустить sshd (достаточно, чтобы он принимал соединения только с localhost).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если клиентов много, то каждому ведь надо свободный порт пробросить? А если кто-то догадается подключиться и пробросить занятый порт, то другой клиент будет страдать от этого или новый клиент не сможет пробросить уже проброшенный порт?

Comment: 1. пробрасывать порты будут клиенты, на стороне сервера никаких «пробросов». 2. да, для каждого подключения нужна своя уникальная пара портов. не знаю, как вы там планируете организовать процесс, но можно, например, динамически выдавать номера по запросу от клиента. 3. нет, пробросить два одновременных соединения на один и тот же порт невозможно.